# Creating a new text file by looking up values in another using awk/linux and transforming data

Tags: linux, join, awk, text, cut

I have two tables:

1. An assoc.logistic file from PLINK (https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/formats#assoc_linear) which I have edited to have the columns using awk (just printing different columns). The number/letters in the SNP column refer to the CHROM/POS/REF/ALT columns in table 2.

   ```
    SNP           P   
    chr1:1243:A:T 0.14 
    chr5:1432:G:C 0.0006
   ```

With millions more lines

2. A reference table from dbSNP which I have edited to have the columns using awk. The chromosome are all written like this annoyingly but the number before the "." is the chromosome i.e. NC_0000001.11 = 1 up to NC_000000022.11 although there are some other random CHROMs assigned to those SNPs that are either mitochondrial or on the sex chromosome (which I am not interested in at present).

> ```
> CHROM         POS  ID         REF ALT  
> NC_0000001.11 1243 rs73647921 A   T  
>
> NC_0000005.11 1432 rs75444    G   C
> ```

with hundreds of millions of further lines

I would like to create an output that looks like this:

```
MarkerName  P-value
rs73647921 0.14
rs75444    0.0006
```

I.E. I would like to convert the CHROM column in table 2 to just the chromosome number 1-22 in the chr[1-22] format and then match the ID to the SNP from table 1 outputting the ID and the P-value in a new table.

I have been using R to do this using a combination of string split to create a new dataframe from table 1 and then using a join/merge function on table 2 but the files are so big this takes ages.

**So far I have tried:**

- to turn table 1 into a format similar to table 2 as table 2 is massive (7G zipped) using awk (I manually deleted the headers):

  awk -F":" '$1=$1' OFS="/t" table1.txt > table1_edited.txt

Giving me:

```
 chr1 1243 A T 0.14 
 chr5 1432 G C 0.0006
```

- and then change the chromosome names in column 1 of table1 into those names found in table2:

  awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {for (i in a)sub(i,a[i]);print' lookup_table.txt table1_edited.txt > new_table.txt

This seems to work with those chromosomes that are single digits but with those that are double digits I get odd results - the lookup table looks like this:

```
chr1 NC_0000001.11 
chr2 NC_0000002.11
..
chr22 NC_0000022.11
```

The code above output looks like this:

```
NC_000001.11 1243 A T 0.14 - as expected for chr1
```

but if the replacement chr was chr17 then I get:

```
NC_000001.117 543 G C 0.005
```

As opposed to:

```
 NC_000017.11 543 G C 0.005
```

Once I've solved this problem and got the formatting right I was hoping to use the join command (I think that's the best one?) to match these to table2 and end up with the outcome of rsID and P-value:

```
 SNP           P   
        chr1:1243:A:T 0.14 
        chr5:1432:G:C 0.0006
```

I would like a command line method of approaching this problem and any help would be greatly appreciated.

All the best

Comment: It is highly encouraged to show your own effort and how it failed, so we can help you with specific hints. If you want someone to write code for you, I suggest hiring a freelancer.

Comment: Dear @rethab, any thanks for the comments. i have added my working up to now, your expert ee would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output values don't match the input data.  Assuming that it is a typo, if you have enough memory something like this should work fast enough

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {if(NR>1) {split($1,f,":"); a[f[1]]=$2} next} 
       FNR==1  {print "MarketName","P-value"; next} 
               {split($1,f,"[_.]"); k=f[2]+0; print "rs"k, a["chr"k]}' file1 file2
```

will generate

```
MarketName P-value
rs1 0.14
rs5 0.0006
```

note that this assumes the given structure in field formats and there was no attempt for error handling.

Comment: many thanks for taking the time to answer. I have amendedmy question with the typos. In fact I was looking to pull the entire rsID not just the first letter, how would I edit the code to reflect that?

Comment: I have also added my working up until now and again, really appreciate you taking the time to answer

Comment: for that just repalce`"rs"k` with `$3`